# Swift 2: expression is ambiguous?

Tags: swift2

The following code used to work before I migrated to Swift 2 now I can't seem to work around it:

```
let cal = NSCalendar(calendarIdentifier: GregorianCalendar)
let components = cal!.components(.CalendarUnitDay | .CalendarUnitMonth | .CalendarUnitYear, fromDate: date) **error at this line**
let newDate = cal!.dateFromComponents(components)
```

I'm getting the following error message:

> Type of expression is ambiguous without more context

Comment: Did you run the Swift 2 migrator in the Edit menu? I'm surprised it didn't fix that for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Swift 2 there is a change in the declaration of `NSCalendarUnit` as well as in the handling of `OptionSetType`

```
let cal = NSCalendar(calendarIdentifier: NSCalendarIdentifierGregorian)
let components = cal!.components([.Day, .Month, .Year], fromDate: date)
```

Please folks read the [Swift Blog](https://developer.apple.com/swift/blog/) and the current Swift Language Guide

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix the error by force typecasting

```
 let components = calendar.components([.Hour, .Minute, .Second], fromDate: date as! NSDate)
```